# Streaming audio to headless linux box

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, audio-streaming, raspberry-pi

I have a dual boot (Win 7 + Ubuntu) PC connected via wifi with my music collection on a local HDD. I usually use Rhythmbox on Ubuntu or Winamp on Windows to listen to my music but I'll change if I have to.

I also have a Raspberry Pi (low power PC running Debian) in the living room that is usually headless and connected via ethernet. The Raspberry Pi is also connected to my living room speakers via an amp.

I would like to be able to stream music from my PC over the network to the linux raspberry pi. What software can I use to do this? Some sort of audio client\server?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this.

- Install [Logitech Media Server](http://www.mysqueezebox.com/download) on your PC. It is available for Windows and Linux, your choice.
- Install [SqueezePlug](http://www.squeezeplug.eu/?page_id=52) Raspberry Pi Image. Configure it as player.

You can now control the music from your PC, or smartphone. The Raspberry Pi works as a server if you put music on your USB harddisk. It has slow performance, but it works.